# only http status been caught and not the JSON error response

Tags: react-native, axios

The backend API responds with HTTP Status 400 and error messages as follows:

```
  {detail: 'msg'}
```

It works well on web portal but with the following code, I can't read the response data:

```
try {
  let res = await axios.post(APIS.START.LOGIN, loginData);

} catch (e) {
  console.log(69, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the body of the failed request by referencing `e.response.data`.

Simply replace `console.log(69, e)` with `console.log(69, e.response.data)`